# Tablesorter not sorting in Chrome

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, tablesorter

So I've got:

```
 $("#tblId").tablesorter({
                    widgets: ['zebra'],
                    widgetOptions: {
                        zebra: ["zebraStripe", "zebraBase"]
                    }
                }).bind("sortStart", function () {
                    alert('sortStart');
                });
```

and the zebra striping is applied to both Chrome and IE 8 (my other browser I'm testing).  But the sortStart function only gets called in IE 8, not Chrome.  It also only sorts in IE 8 and not in Chrome, which is the real issue.  Can anyone add lend any thoughts?  TIA.

EDIT:  I fixed the mismatched quotes.  When I simplified the selector from:

```
$('#tblChildViolationList_' + entityid + '[data-violationtype="' + violationType + '"]')
```

to:

```
 $("#tblId")
```

I didn't pay attention to the quotes.

Comment: If your code is exactly this I'd change `$('#tblId")` to `$('#tblId')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of `'` and `"` characters at the start. Try:

```
$("#tblId").tablesorter({
                widgets: ['zebra'],
                widgetOptions: {
                    zebra: ["zebraStripe", "zebraBase"]
                }
            }).bind("sortStart", function () {
                alert('sortStart');
            });
```

instead. `"` and `'` are both valid string delimiters, but you need to be consistent within a single string.

Answer (score 0):

> $('#tblId")

check your apostrophes